# Need some help regarding calculations involving natural logarithm

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I wanted to calculate the values of $\log_e{10^n}$ for $n=1,2 \dots 30$.

I tried simplifying $\log_e{10^n}$ as $n\log_e{10}$. It can be re-written as $n\cdot 2.3025$ but I am getting inaccurate results.

I tried using calculator but it is showing different values for $\log_e{10^n}$ and $n\log_e{10}$ which is not accurate. I don't have any knowledge on Mathematica. Can someone help me with finding these values?
I want that $|\log_e n-a_n| \leq 10^{-3}$ where $a_n$ are the computed values for $n=1 \dots 30$. 
You can suggest ways

Comment: How accurate do you need the results to be? What do you mean by "getting inaccurate results"? Can you show what you did for $n = 1, 2, 3$?

Comment: order upto $10^{-3}$, that is $|\log_e n-a_n| \leq 10^{-3}$ where $a_n$ are the computed values.

Comment: Try $\log_e(10)=2.30258509299405$